# How to apply annotation to getter of delegated property in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, jackson, annotations, jvm

While Using Kotlin I wanted to add package-defined constant as a prefix for serialized class property. Jackson is bro, so I wrote this:

```kotlin
var prop: String = ""
    @JsonGetter(value = "prop")
    get() = PREFIX + field
```

It worked fine, so I decided to replace it with delegated property for brevity:

```kotlin
@get:JsonGetter(value = "prop") var prop: String by PrefixedProperty()

...

class PrefixedProperty(var field: String = "") {
    operator fun getValue(blah blah) = PREFIX + field
    ...
}
```

And BOOM — my property disappeared.

It seems, annotation was not applied to `prop`'s delegated getter. Is it even possible to achieve the desired behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

You should annotate it like this:

```
@delegate:JsonGetter(value = "prop") var prop: String by PrefixedProperty()
```

Comment: Hey there! Thanks for answer.
Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me. It says ```This annotation is not applicable to target 'member property with delegate' and use site target '@delegate'```

Comment: You should use these dependencies:

```com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core
com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind
com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations
com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin
```